# Interpreting ARIMA for ITSA

Tags: r, time-series

I want to test for efficacy of an intervention. I have pre- and post-intervention data and I used `auto.arima` to find the best fit for the two data sets.

I'm stuck in the actual use of these models now. What do I do with the `auto.arima` fit? Can I graph it and test for statistically significant differences in the coefficients? If so, how do I graph it?

This is what I have right now ( specified from `auto.arima`)

`myPreFit<-arima(myPre,order=c(0,1,0))
 myPostFit<-arima(myPost,order=c(1,0,1))`

Comment: If you have questions about statistical modeling, you should ask over at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic. This is not a specific programming question so it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry.